# Raspi crashing when operating USB Stick

Tags: usb

I have a raspbian installed on SD on my raspi 3 and I wanted to download a crypto currency and compile it on the pi. However my SD is just 8GB and already full so I wanted to run that whole compiling process from USB. However when I try to download the project using git clone, the ssh connection dies and when I reconnect, the raspi has rebooted, all mounts are gone and I have to start again.

First thought was maybe a damaged USB stick so I tried another one. It's a new 32GB stick but the same happens.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The power the device pulls seems normal 200mA

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo lsusb -v|grep Power
  (Bus Powered)
MaxPower              200mA
```

I also tried upgrading and dist-upgrading the device but that didn't help either. What could be the problem here?

Edit: Same happens now when I try to pull it to the SD card?

```
remote: Counting objects: 22788, done.
remote: Total 22788 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 22788
Receiving objects: 100% (22788/22788), 23.12 MiB | 2.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:  85% (14527/17044)
```

Stops and reboots at 19% or 70% or 85% or any other random %

Comment: the title of your post is misleading

Answer (score 1):

If your SD card is already full, then you will not be able to get any new data in it. The pi keeps rebooting as the card becomes overloaded. You need to get a bigger SD card or delete some big files.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a full card. I wrote that it crashes on USB stick too. Also your assumption that Pi reboots when SD card is full makes no sense at all.

Comment: @user6329530 Actually, it makes a lot of sense. Try running that `git clone` command with `sudo`: if it works this time, you are likely out of space for regular users to save data.